# expand td to image width 100% with hover text

Tags: html, css, hover, html-table, background-image

I am trying to use table cells with a background image and transparent text and when you hover over the background image (the td cell) the text appears in a transparent black box.

How do I get the td cell to expand to the entire size of the background image, a width of 100% filling the entire td?

Here is my JS Fiddle where I tried two different approaches (background-size:contain; background-size: cover; and background-size: 100% auto;):
https://jsfiddle.net/wpdyjLgd/#&togetherjs=Bp5OxozhEt

Edited CSS (only includes issue - JSFiddle includes all)

```
.HomeBody2 {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  cellspacing: 0;
  cellpadding: 0;
}

#HomeBody2 {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  cellspacing: 0;
  cellpadding: 0;
}

.HomeBody2 h1 {
  font-family: "Footlight MT Light";  
  font-size: 56px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  color: #062F4F;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.HomeBody2 h2 {
  font-family: "Georgia"; 
  color: #FF3B3F; 
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;  
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.HomeBody2 p {
  font-family: "Georgia";  
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: none;
  margin: 0;
  color: transparent;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.HomeBody2 a {
  color: #FF3B3F;
  font-family: "Georgia";  
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

table td.Why:hover {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: url("images/Money.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: center;
}

table td.Why:hover > p {
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
  background-color: #000000;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

table td.Why {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: url("images/Money.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: center;
}

table td.How:hover {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: url("images/PeopleWorking.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: center;
}

table td.How:hover > p {
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
  background-color: #000000;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

table td.How {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: url("images/PeopleWorking.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: center;
}


  <table class="HomeBody2" width="100%">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="Why" width="33.5%">
          <p>Spend less on administrative burdens by finding everyday solutions for your agency. Every dollar saved is a minute spent on other important tasks like analysis and policy.</p>
        </td>
        <td class="How" width="66.5%">
          <p>We start with a demonstration of a potential solution, often one used by another Federal agency, since our best solutions are ones that have broad applicability. Then we move into a discovery process, determining your agency's needs. From there, we build a prototype, refine and reiterate that prototype, and enter testing once the agency is satisfied. Following more refining, the solution enters a pilot project, then moving into a live production environment for the end results. We work in an agile environment, meaning new solutions are always around the corner, offering capabilities to current and potential clients.</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to cut the example code down to the minimum size needed to demonstrate the issue? I'm sure you don't need all those hundreds of lines of css.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand - have a look at the why and how td in this --> https://jsfiddle.net/9eLfc07h/  -- Is that what you mean by making the image the size of the td? Or is it something to do with the text you wanted..?

Comment: Hi Ovokuro, kind of. Ideally I want the entire picture of one of the cells (i.e. the how picture being 100% of the td and cutting off a portion of the why picture) to show in the td without having to add <br> above and below the text to expand the td to show more of the picture. Thanks!